# Incorrect sort key when querying from DynamoDB (node js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS dynamodb to store some data. This table has 'key' as 'Primary partition key' and 'create_micro_time_float' as 'Primary sort key'.

My data in the table is something like this.

```
{
    'key': {'S': 'xxx'},
    'create_micro_time_float': {'N': 1499844782.50379992}
}, ...
```

But when I use 'scan' operation (to retrieve all data in the table), I got something like this.

```
{
    'key': {'S': 'xxx'},
    'create_micro_time_float': {'N': 1499844782.5037999}
}, ...
```

The last decimal point of my 'Primary sort key' is missing.

The problem is I want to update all record in the table but now I have an incorrect sort key. I need a correct sort key in order to update the record in the table.

How can I do this (with [nodejs dynamodb aws sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html))?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to String type before you send as docs says. Using .toFixed() you keep the precision you want.

From [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html)

> **Number**
>
> Numbers can be positive, negative, or zero. Numbers can have up
> to 38 digits precision. Exceeding this results in an exception.
>
> Positive range: 1E-130 to 9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125
>
> Negative range: -9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125 to
> -1E-130
>
> In DynamoDB, numbers are represented as variable length. Leading and
> trailing zeroes are trimmed.
>
> All numbers are sent across the network to DynamoDB as strings, to
> maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However,
> DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical
> operations.
>
> **Note**
>
> If number precision is important, you should pass numbers to DynamoDB
> using strings that you convert from number type.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I have already stored a lot of data in the table so I can't change the type of data in the table from number to string.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is caused by javascript (js has a limit number length and decimal places), I moved to PHP and use [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) instead. Now it works!